# Translate camera's button text ("Cancel", "Retake" and "Use photo") in SwiftUI

Tags: camera, swiftui, translation

Once I've implemented camera functionality with this great tutorial ( https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/importing-an-image-into-swiftui-using-uiimagepickercontroller ), I wonder if there'd be a way for translating the text of the camera buttons for something other than "Cancel", "Retake" and "Use photo". My goal is translating those texts to portuguese, but I just can't figure out how to do that on SwiftUI.

Comment: have u got any answer?

Comment: Unfortunatelly not, my friend. :-(